# Rabbitmq can't send newletters when over 1000 recipients

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, limit

I have a Rabbitmq server and I wish to send out newletters. The problem is I'm uploading the recipients with a .csv file and if it has more than 1000 lines, the error occurs.

Somehow I suspect the following line to be fault:

```
MQ.fanout(exchange).publish(Marshal.dump(data))
```

The messages are not being transported for the queues or I don't know.

What I can do is: I have to delete the actual "stuck" project because I can't send any onther newsletter feed until it is deleted. After I delete it, the rest of the newsletters will be sent out perfectly.

Edit:

the logs did not show any errors. However, after setting the log to a lower standing, I've got this:

/var/log/rabbitmq/error.log

```
2015-10-28 10:34:33.353 [error] <0.1182.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.1182.0> (127.0.0.1:45994 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/bposted', user: 'bposted', state: running), channel 0:
{amqp_error,connection_forced,"broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'",none}

2015-10-28 10:52:11.336 [error] <0.364.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.364.0> (127.0.0.1:46042 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/bposted', user: 'bposted', state: running), channel 1:
{amqp_error,frame_error,"type 3, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,4319180,131064}",none}

2015-10-28 10:52:14.342 [error] <0.364.0> closing AMQP connection <0.364.0> (127.0.0.1:46042 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
fatal_frame_error
```

This might be a clue?

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: Yes, check please the post

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.5.6"} ? I don't know, really sorry, I've inherited the server and never seen anything like this before

Comment: Oh yes, and it is on a ruby enviroment :(

Comment: I imagined it. Try to increase  `frame_max`  and check your `bunny` version:
https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/issues/97

Comment: {amqp_error,frame_error,"type 3, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,4319180,131064}",none} 

the negotiated frame size is 131064 and the frame that you try to pass has 4319180.  update the frame_max property or split your payload before send.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
{frame_too_large,4319180,131064}
```

Try to increase `frame_max` parameter as described here https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {frame_max, 4319180},
    ]
  } 
].
```

Comment: Did 50000000 for frame_max, but came up with this error now:

==> /var/log/rabbitmq/error.log <==
2015-10-28 11:42:43.099 [error] <0.377.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.377.0> (127.0.0.1:46454 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/bposted', user: 'bposted', state: running), channel 1:
{amqp_error,frame_error,"type 3, all octets = <<>>: {frame_too_large,1542718,131064}",none}

2015-10-28 11:42:46.101 [error] <0.377.0> closing AMQP connection <0.377.0> (127.0.0.1:46454 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
fatal_frame_error

Comment: BTW, this is a 5 years old install of a server with Ruby and there is not even a gem file, so I suspect it was installed from source :/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately we have found the sollution. It was basically what CHAPa said, the rabbitmq was able to recieve bigger frames than the standard (we've set the frame_max for 0). But couldn't find the AMQP file that passes the info. This is where we have found it:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/amqp-0.7.0/lib/amqp/client.rb
```

And had to change the frame_max value to 0 manually. From this point, it works like a charm. :) Thank you for the advices.

BTW: If I'm gonna be in charge when we scrap this server, I won't upgrade it, or install another Rabbitmq server. PHPlist is my style :) Vote please this up, so it can be on top when somebody searches it.